# Is there an efficent way to share java Image/Raster pixel memory between Java and native code using Panama or JNI or (?)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, project-panama

I have a C++ library that does image processing on rectangular arrays of pixels.
I want to pass the output C++ pixels to java so they can most effciently be "drawn" into a java.awt.Graphics2 instance for a canvas as an Image/Raster/(?) object( yeah not the best way but it is a legacy app )

I am looking for the best way to do this for performance, as the image can be "animated" and updates need to be reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

The backing store for a `Raster` object is a `DataBuffer`, which is an interface you can implement yourself. If you use a `DirectByteBuffer` you can effectively share a memory region between Java and the native world.

Comment: I will check this out.  Hopefully it can do a block copy of an entire scan line at a time when it gets to draw time :)

Comment: So far the only way I managed to do this is by using the sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster. which is the only one one can assign an externally allocated byte[]/DataBufferByte to as a buffer and also have it efficiently do the graphics2D.draw(image). efficiently into.